# Cyclic relationship between tables

Tags: database, schema, dax, powerbi

We have some fact tables (Database Opened / Database Available) in Power BI that reference columns in multiple common reference tables (All Databases / events):

[image]

(There's other fact/refernce tables, that bring togetehr users-events-sessions , etc.)

One of the relations can't be activated (Database Available -> All Databases), as it says there is already an active set of indirect relationships.

When we're adding some measures to All Databases, so we can count the number of users, number of owners, and % owners that used the database, it just can't seem to resolve the dependency between Database Available -> All Databases correctly.

It feels like we've got the schema and relationships wrong, but I can't see how to better organise this data. It also feels like a common issue which will have a solution, but I can't seem to find it after searching.

What is the best approach in these scenarios? Is there a pattern to follow to remove this cyclic dependency?

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to offer advice based just on that diagram... but I'll have a go.

I think I would try to append your [Database Opened] and [Database Available]tables into a single table e.g. [Database Events], with an extra column e.g. [Event] with values of "Database Opened" or "Database Available".

I would do this in the Edit Queries window, and then set your current [Database Opened] and [Database Available] tables to not load.  Then you will have a clean "star schema" set of 3 tables with simple relationships.

This design will also likely be more flexible and useful for your visualizations.

Comment: Thanks for the input Mike. As our schema got more complicated, and after doing more reading, we realised we should stick to one way relationships. We ended up with 2 Fact tables, one for ownership and one for use, and they share the Dim_Database table (+other dimensions). It seems to work quite well, and I think we ended up with a good and well design approach that should help with further extensions :)